# Coroutine tests break automatically assigned id for ObjectBox Entity in Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

I'm running a set of tests on the database using `.directory(TEST_DIRECTORY)` as instructed [in the docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/android/android-local-unit-tests). There's a `setUp()` and a `tearDown()` for `@Before` and `@After`, respectively.

I test the following cases:

1. queries on the database return empty lists for all three **suspend** functions declared in the interface
2. for each **suspend** function, I test the outcome

What is strange is the following:

1. the empty lists queries succeed
2. out of the three functions that suppose to return an entity populated object, two of them fail and one of them succeeds

This makes me wonder: is there a possibility that the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` don't work as expected?

The error I get is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID is higher or equal to internal ID sequence: 1 (vs. 1). Use ID 0 (zero) to insert new entities.
```

for both of the failing test cases (to reiterate: one of them is succeeding so the population of entities in the database works as expected for this [always] one test case but fails [always] for the other two test cases).

In an **object** I declare a list of Entity instantiations with the id set to `0L` (the default) of the form:

```kotlin
object MyEntitiesMockDataSource {

    ...

    val entityList = listOf(
        MyEntity(
            parameterOne = "someValueOne",
            parameterTwo = someValueOne,
            parameterThree = someValueOne
        ),
        MyEntity(
            parameterOne = "someValueTwo",
            parameterTwo = someValueTwo,
            parameterThree = someValueTwo
        ),
        MyEntity(
            parameterOne = "someValueThree",
            parameterTwo = someValueThree,
            parameterThree = someValueThree
        ),
        ...
}
```

in total of 10 `MyEntity` objects.

The tests are in the form of:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testGetLatest10EntitiesByOwner_populatedBox_emitsExpectedEntitiesByOwner() = runTest {
        val owner = "email@example.com"
        val entities = MyEntityMockDataSource.entityList

        /** Insert test entities into the database */
        boxStore.boxFor<MyEntity>().put(entities)

        repository.getLatest10EntitiesByOwner(owner).test {
            val emission = awaitItem()
            awaitComplete()
            /** reversed() because the query does orderDesc() */
            assertEquals(entities.reversed(), emission)
        }
    }
```

Could it be possible that ObjectBox somehow doesn't delete the database and it then fails after first successful execution of the first (non empty) test case and then hits the second and the third but there're already entities instantiated and thus the ID generation now fails?

How could this be even when the id is set to `0L`? Or is it because of the **suspend** functions? Should I just use regular functions? Will ObjectBox run them asynchronously in **Dispatcher.IO** thread?

I **do not** want to set `@Id(assignable = true)` - I'm sure there's a way to make the tests work without setting `assignable` to `true`.

Comment: So I listed `TEST_DIRECTORY` and I can see the database being created and deleted, but I don't see it missing in between listings of `TEST_DIRECTORY` - could it be the tests run too quickly for the listing to catch it? Command used was `while true; do ls -lhiaR * | egrep '...'; done`

Comment: Running tests individually is successful, however, running the entire tests in the class (running tests in class) is failing.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/1175 to objectbox team.